# import a module from other python folder

Tags: python-3.x

I have a a project with following path:

```
shift/
     Code/
          __init__.py
          mymain.py
          run.py
     Test/
         __init__.py
         tester.py
         runtester.py

     requirments.txt
```

in `mymain.py` there is a class which I need to import from the `tester.py`. So in `tester.py` I'm importing class as following codes but none of them work.

```
from Code.mymain import NewClass
from .mymain import NewClass
from mymain import NewClass
from shift.Code.mymain import NewClass
```

I also tried to insert the path in `tester.py`:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.insert(0, cwd)
```

However still confused why it does not know my file

Comment: ``sys.path.append( os.path.realpath( os.path.dirname(__file__)+"/..") )``  You don't know what getcwd might be.

Comment: Thanks it works. Does it work in other systems as well if I share my project?

Comment: It should work anywhere.  I use this in many of my scripts.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) + '\\Code') 
from mymain import NewClass
```

More details at : [importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/15560363)